# How to filter a Select with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to filter the options in a select that uses ng-options but when I add the filter I get no options at all

```
<select id="players"  ng-model="selectedPlayer" ng-options="player.name for player in players track by player.$id | filter:{live:'true'}">
    <option value="">Select player</option>    
</select>
```

But the filter works fine in an ng-repeat like this

```
<div ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{live:'true'}">
    {{player.name}}   
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had angular `filter` on wrong place. Filter should be applied over a `players` collection, it should not be at the end.

**Markup**

```
<select id="players" ng-model="selectedPlayer" 
  ng-options="player.name for player in players | filter:{live:'true'} track by player.$id">
    <option value="">Select player</option>    
</select>
```